# my javascript for creating unique IDs isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create unique `id`s, and I can't see why it's not working. Guess I'm blind staring at the same code for too long. I would appreciate if someone could help me! :)

```
function laggtill(cool, namnVara) {

  var date = new Date();
  var id = "" + date.getHours() + date.getMinutes() + date.getSeconds() + date.getMilliseconds();

  var vara = document.createElement("li");

  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerText = namnVara;

  vara.appendChild(checkBox);
  vara.appendChild(span);

  cool.appendChild(vara);
}

var button = document.getElementById("knapp");
button.onclick = function() {

  var skriva = document.getElementById("skriva")
  var namnVara = skriva.value;

  if (!namnVara || namnVara == "" || namnVara == " ") {
    return false;
  }

};
```

Comment: Could you specify "not working"?

Comment: You never actually *use* the value of `id`. Did you mean to add it as the `id` attribute of `checkBox` or `span`?

Comment: it doesn't create any IDs, when i look at my elements there's just a span, no ID!

Comment: i want to add it to span!

Answer (score 1):

Stole this from jQuery UI. It's as simple as it's effective:

```
// at initialization
var uuid = 0;

// and when you need a unique id
var uniqueId = 'uid-' + (++uuid);
```

No need for complicated stuff like getting dates etc. `unique != complicated`

And to set the ID to an element:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.id = uniqueId;
```

And if you want to use it more often in a script, you could create a function:

```
var uuid = 0; // put it in the 'global scope'
var uniqueId = function() {
    return 'uid-' + (++uuid);
};

alert(uniqueId()); // uid-1
alert(uniqueId()); // uid-2
```

Comment: I think his main problem is not being able to *set* the ID. You might show that as well

Comment: it's not jQuery ;) just stole the 'logic' from jquery UI source

Comment: It's preferable to change properties instead of attributes. And `element.id = uniqueId;` is shorter.

Comment: Thanks @Oriol! good suggestion, edited the question yet again ;)

Comment: i tried this, and it gave my item an id but when i added one new item it got the same id as the frist one. @giorgio

Comment: @MoaLarssonn I'd advise you to use the function (`uniqueId()` -> watch the parentheses). And don't forget to put the `uuid` var _outside_ the function. That way everytime you'll get a new id. If you don't use the function you should increase the variable yourself each time (`++uuid`)

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to keep the date.

```
var d = new Date();
var id = "" + d.getHours() + d.getMinutes() + d.getSeconds()+ d.getMilliseconds();
```

add some stuff to generate guid to :

```
var guid = (function() {
function s4() {
return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
           .toString(16)
           .substring(1);
}
return function() {
 return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
       s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
};
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mz4qpg1L/1/

if you want to append id to youre control, i like appending html directly :

```
vara.appendChild('<span id=' + id + ' ></span>');
```

this way you can put any attribute you want.